# Get specific modified date format from WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, orders

Im using `get_the_modified_date()` function to get the last date an order was updated, Im trying to send the format this way:

```
get_the_modified_date( "F j, Y, g:i a", $order );
```

But I get an empty string, if I remove the format argument:

```
get_the_modified_date( $order );
```

I get the following output:

```
{"2413":64365,"pamLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:00131_2413":0,"2031am3100000020":"13-05:00lunes24000-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:0013","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00000000Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:0012020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020":"C-0500-05:00","000-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500202420201":"4.7.1","pLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500242020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:0020_2412020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00lunes00000013-05:00_31amx":famlunes20-05:00,"13am31-05:00_2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:00am31-05:0013":{"13am31-05:00":"2020-11-26 19:53:49.000000","312401-05:001220201-05:00_3120p-05:00":1,"312401-05:001220201-05:00":"+00:00"},"13am31-05:00_0120201324f24-05:0013":{"13am31-05:00":"2020-11-29 00:27:41.000000","312401-05:001220201-05:00_3120p-05:00":1,"312401-05:001220201-05:00":"+00:00"},"1324202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020000000131_31202031amlunes":"0","1324202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020000000131_31amx":"0","201124pp24111_31202031amlunes":"16000","201124pp24111_31amx":"0","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050031_31amx":"0","31202031amlunes":"111000","31202031amlunes_31amx":"0","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:000000002031202001-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_2413":601,"2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050013-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_k-05:0020":"12020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00_2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050013-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_113VthAM-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500072510002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:001","b24luneslunes24111":{"f24Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002031_1am01-05:00":"amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am111-05:00lunes 20-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:003120","lunesam2031_1am01-05:00":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001pam120":"","am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_1":"2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500am 16 12020 26-24","am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_2":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00243120":"AMLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050001-05:00124am","2031am31-05:00":"Q15789326600","p202020312020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202013-05:00":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020000000131Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050020":"C-0500","-05:0001am24lunes":"am1301241@amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am111-05:00lunes20-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:003120.2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001","p1120201-05:00":"3206280962"},"201124pp24111":{"f24Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002031_1am01-05:00":"amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am111-05:00lunes 20-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:003120","lunesam2031_1am01-05:00":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001pam120":"","am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_1":"2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500am 16 12020 26-24","am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_2":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00243120":"AMLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050001-05:00124am","2031am31-05:00":"Q15789326600","p202020312020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202013-05:00":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020000000131Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050020":"C-0500"},"pam2001-05:00131_01-05:003111202013":"120202020-01-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00am132020-pam112020-bam20242020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00","pam2001-05:00131_01-05:003111202013_312431lunes-05:00":"-05:00am11am p2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500 Ef-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:003120, GMT-0500amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050013-05:0031am 13-05:00 2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500u00-05:0091324312020, -05:00thE, -05:00312020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00","31Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500am120am2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00312420201_2413":"","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:000000002031202001-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_24p_am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020":"181.51.186.231","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:000000002031202001-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_00000020-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_am11-05:00131":"Ene20201224luneslunesam/5.0 (Eneam2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002413120202011; 0131-05:00lunes Eneam2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00 -0500th X 10_14_6) AMpplunes-05:0003-05:00bK2431/537.36 (K11GMT-0500Ene1, lunes24k-05:00 11-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00k2020) C11Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500202001-05:00/86.0.4240.198 thamfamLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050024/537.36","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:00am31-05:0013_00024am":"2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00k202000000031","2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:000000002031202001-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_1202031-05:00":"","13am31-05:00_2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001plunes-05:0031-05:0013":{"13am31-05:00":"2020-11-26 19:58:19.000000","312401-05:001220201-05:00_3120p-05:00":1,"312401-05:001220201-05:00":"+00:00"},"13am31-05:00_pam2413":{"13am31-05:00":"2020-11-26 19:58:19.000000","312401-05:001220201-05:00_3120p-05:00":1,"312401-05:001220201-05:00":"+00:00"},"2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050031_11am2011":"-05:002b692375182020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00b13265f62020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00742f13132649am1","100000001b-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500":"64365","01-05:0031am_13am31am":[{"2413":1133460,"k-05:0020":"01am24lunes2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00112401p_1202020202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020200101-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00_2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00am01pam24111_2413","000amlunes000000-05:00":""},{"2413":1133461,"k-05:0020":"01am24lunes2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00112401p_1202020202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020200101-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00_lunesam11324111_202431-05:00","000amlunes000000-05:00":"113131p20://-05:00bam124.2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001.2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020/1p-am1301241/am1301241-am13amx.p11p?am2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00312420201=01am24lunes2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00112401p_20-05:0031_00000020-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_b20_-05:0001am24lunes&-05:0001am24lunes=am1301241@amLun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am111-05:00lunes20-05:002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:003120.2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00202001&012020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00_lunesam111000000am11-05:00=-05:0020"},{"2413":1133493,"k-05:0020":"_b24luneslunes24111_2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:0013000000lunesam","000amlunes000000-05:00":"123456789"},{"2413":1133494,"k-05:0020":"_b24luneslunes24111_am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_13-05:0031am24lunes20","000amlunes000000-05:00":"amb2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0013-05:00f11"},{"2413":1133495,"k-05:0020":"_201124pp24111_am1313Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:002020_13-05:0031am24lunes20","000amlunes000000-05:00":"amb2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0013-05:00f11"},{"2413":1133496,"k-05:0020":"2420_000am31_-05:00x-05:0001p31","000amlunes000000-05:00":"12020"},{"2413":1133497,"k-05:0020":"11am20_20000000b_2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050013-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500","000amlunes000000-05:00":"1"},{"2413":1133572,"k-05:0020":"_12020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00_fam2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00b20202020k_f2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_1202020202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020200101-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00_2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050013-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_plunesam2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:0013","000amlunes000000-05:00":"20-05:0020"},{"2413":1133573,"k-05:0020":"01am24lunes2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00112401p_1202020202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020200101-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00_2420_20000000b202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -050024b-05:0013","000amlunes000000-05:00":"1"},{"2413":1133574,"k-05:0020":"_00000020-05:0013_11am31-05:001am20","000amlunes000000-05:00":"03C_0320202020Ene-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00am132020-05:00am112020_725am20242020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am31-05:001am20"},{"2413":1133575,"k-05:0020":"Ene-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00am132020 -05:00am112020 - -05:00am2001-05:00131 12421202211","000amlunes000000-05:00":"[Lunam31-05:00 2020-11-26 19:54:07]/[AM012020000000131 111000]/[-05:00am2413 111000]/[R-05:00f000000113 0]"},{"2413":1133576,"k-05:0020":"_Ene-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00am132020_-05:00am112020_-05:00am2001-05:00131_0Lun20","000amlunes000000-05:00":"12421202211"},{"2413":1133577,"k-05:0020":"_11am_31Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500am2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00k-05:0013","000amlunes000000-05:00":"1"},{"2413":1133578,"k-05:0020":"_12020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00_fam2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00b20202020k_f2020Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500_1202020202020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020200101-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00-05:00_p000000Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -05002020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0011am20-05:00_31Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500am2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:00k-05:0013","000amlunes000000-05:00":"20-05:0020"},{"2413":1133579,"k-05:0020":"_0311LunR_2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:0020201000-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500202420201_p24x-05:00lunes_f24Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:0013","000amlunes000000-05:00":"31Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500000000-05:00"},{"2413":1133724,"k-05:0020":"_240002020lunes-05:00_Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:0000024-05:001_Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500-05:000124113-05:00Lun, 13 Ene 2020 11:24:20 -0500","000amlunes000000-05:00":"0"}],"lunes241-05:00_2431-05:000120":{"6443":{},"6444":{}},"31amx_lunes241-05:0020":[],"201124pp24111_lunes241-05:0020":{"6445":{},"6446":{}},"f-05:00-05:00_lunes241-05:0020":[],"2020-01-13T11:24:20-05:002020000000p20201_lunes241-05:0020":[]}
```

Could you please tell me why the date format is not working with this function?

Comment: have you tried `$order->id` or `$post->id;` ?

Comment: It worked! well I think this documentation is wrong? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_date/

Comment: In the parameters it says post id